# Sort date ListArray along with a second Array for the Title

Tags: java, android, sorting, date

I have this for sorting the dates:

```
Collections.sort(calDate, new Comparator<String>() { 
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d, yyyy h");
    @Override
    public int compare(String date1, String date2) {
        try {
            return f.parse(date1).compareTo(f.parse(date2));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
});
```

The title and dates are getting pulled from a calendar rss feed. I have them saved in two different arrays (`calDate`, `calTitle`).

Based off the order the events are added to the calendar, the events won't be in order.

calDate holds Wed Feb 10, 2016 11:30am to 12:30pm, Wed Sep 30, 2015 11:30am to 12:30pm, Wed Sep 23, 2015 9:30pm to 10:30pm

calTitle holds Feb 10th Event, Sep 30th Event, Sep 23rd Event

I am trying to order them like this

calDate reordered: Wed Sep 23, 2015 9:30pm to 10:30pm, Wed Sep 30, 2015 11:30am to 12:30pm, Wed Feb 10, 2016 11:30am to 12:30pm

calTitle holds  Sep 23rd Event, Sep 30th Event, Feb 10th Event

Comment: You might have to describe the problem in more detail. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I added what I believe should describe the problem better. I can sort the Dates fine, but not sure how to get the Titles to sort with them.

Comment: You question is confusing. You refer to MainActivity.CalDate as an array, but if so then you violate Java naming conventions with an uppercase name on `CalDate`. And the `MainActivity.` suggests they are static members rather than instance variables. Is `MainActivity` an instance or a class? Is the date and title both instance members on the same object? If the date and the title are completely separate, then you should use a Map with the date as the key and the title as the value. I suggest you work on mastering the basics of Java, then get a grasp on Collections such as Map and Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build an association between title and date in order to sort by one field and maintain that association. The easiest thing to do is to create a new object with a title field and a date field then create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). You probably have some other fields in the RSS feed that you would like to keep there as well.

Also, please don't parse a string inside compareTo, do it in the setter of the new class that you create.

Comment: I believe I know what I have to do based off what you are saying, I will try this out in a little bit. Thank you for your comment!